# How can I shift leaflet map bounds without repeating the tiles?

Tags: leaflet

I have a codepen demonstrating the issue at https://codepen.io/ericg_off/pen/KKoJvbK

I am using leaflet 1.8.0.

I have adjusted the map's maxBounds (`const maxBounds = [[-90, -480], [90, -120]];`) so the left and right edges of the map are

Left Edge [image: left edge] ----- Right Edge [image]

To accomplish this, I needed to allow the tileLayer to wrap around the antemeridian...so noWrap retains the default value of true.

So, when I zoom out, I get:

[image: zoomed out]

But, I would like to have similar behavior to what would happen if I left the maxBounds set to `const maxBounds = [[-90, -180], [90, 180]];` and set `noWrap: true` which would look like:

[image: zoomed out default]

i.e. the gray background outside of the maxBounds.

How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

JS:

```
const maxBounds = [
  [-90, -480],
  [90, -120]
];

// const maxBounds = [
//   [-90, -180],
//   [90, 180]
// ];

var map = L.map("map", {
  center: [38.89, -77.03],
  zoom: 3,
  maxBounds
});

var tiles = new L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 8,
    // noWrap: true
  }
).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Set the `maxBounds` of the `L.TileLayer` as well.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, that does not resolve the issue. [TileLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer) does not have a maxBounds option. I do see a bounds option. However, setting `bounds: maxBounds` does not resolve the issue.